# Does Safari associate a browser window name with the domain that opened it?

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit

I have a multiple-domain network of sites.  In one domain, some javascript opens a new smaller window and gives it a name of "controls".  If you go to a second domain and click to open "controls" again (same window name), it opens a new window rather than updating the one that already exists.

Is it possible that Safari associates the domain with the opened window so that one domain doesn't accidentally (or mischievously) change another domain's window?  Other browsers (non-Webkit, at least) don't seem to behave this way.  I haven't been able to find any clear explanation of what the logic here is.

Answer (score 0):

No, what you are looking for is called session ID.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm actually unable to use sessions in this case, and I'm only trying to open a new window, not track user behavior.


openwin('http://www.example.com/mypage.html', 'mywindow', 'width=100,height=300');